# On access, how do I add an "if" statement based off of different records?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a list of training that people have to take based off their title, this list goes like this

```
Violence and Harassment
First Aid
Whmis
Fire hazard and awareness
Fire Extinguisher
```

And then I have a table that specifies the training needed based off the title, it looks like this

```
Supervisor | First Aid
Supervisor | Fire hazard and awareness
Driver | Whmis
Driver| Fire extinguisher
```

and it goes on like that.

The problem is that there is some inconsistency in the company. A couple of the courses are equivalent, like the fire hazard and awareness is equal to fire extinguisher, BUT the required training is listed as above.

I have a query afterwards that pulls together the training that each person has taken, but I am having trouble with the equivalent courses.  It creates the combinations of all supervisors and the training courses they need so, it looks like this.

```
Supervisor | Joe | First Aid | May 21 2016
```

Also a query that identifies the any missing training.

In the above list, if a supervisor took fire extinguisher instead of fire hazard and awareness, I don't want it to identify that they are missing fire hazard and awareness. Where would I put this "if" statement?

EDIT:

Here is the Select statement that pulls up all the "missing" training where in the example the supervisor takes "Fire Extinguisher`instead of the listed`Fire hazard and awareness`, the`Fire hazard and awareness` shows up as not taken even though they have taken an equivalent.

```
SELECT TakenAndReqTraining.Training, TakenAndReqTraining.EmployeeName, TakenAndReqTraining.DateTaken, TakenAndReqTraining.Expiry
FROM TakenAndReqTraining
WHERE (((TakenAndReqTraining.DateTaken) Is Null)) OR (((TakenAndReqTraining.Expiry)<=Now()));
```

*looks for null where there is not date associated with the course and employee meaning that they have not taken it, and also '=Now() to look for expired.

Comment: I'm guessing your 'final' query locates unmatched records to report missing training. For me it would be easiest if you had a 'code' added to the course file that you could key off of instead of the name of the course. Thus 'FIRE' could appear in two course records, and could also appear in the 'required' table also. That way you don't need to worry about changing if someone changes a course name.

Answer (score 0):

You have to stablish common ground between the two related trainings.
There is no easy way to check for equivalent trainings if they are only strings.

Create an *TrainingID* field, numeric, on the table that specifies training needed. Then assign every training a number on that field, so that equivalent trainings are assigned the same number. Meaning that your query that identifies missing trainings would identify by that number and not based on strings.

This way you can perform the identification of missing trainings by that field. This is the best way to mantain scalability.

Otherwise, you must write a switch in the select query, in which you include an expression evaluation for each of the trainings that have an equivalent.

EDIT:

I tend to work with small databases, and if the tables are 1 to 500 records this solution might work, once again, this is not the best way to go in the long run. It is slow and ugly, and even uglier if you use switch in the query.

Inside the query using switch:
You must first transform the training to an equivalent if there is one, then check if the employee has the equivalent. Add an expression as follows:

```
Equivalent: switch(Training="Fire Extinguisher","Fire Hazard and Awareness",Training="Fire Hazard and Awareness","Fire Extinguisher",Training="Training#2", "Equivalent#2")
```

You need to add every equivalent trainings here.

Then check if the employee has the equivalent with a second expression:

```
HasEquivalent: nz(Dlookup("Training","TakenAndReqTraining","Employee='" & employee & "' AND Training='" & Equivalent & "' AND (DateTaken is not null) AND (TakenAndReqTraining.Expiry)<=Now()" ),"")
Criteria: <> ""
```

You can also create a function in vba to do execute equally so you don't have to deal with the expression builder.

Comment: I added the select query that I use to pull out the missing training. I`m a little confused with how to use the switch function in this situation.

Comment: I believe the 'switch' means you would need code inside your Query that could check for a returned value and 'switch' it to another. Like: Iif(CourseName = 'Fire Ext','Fire hazard and awareness',{CourseName]). This is really not a good way to go!

Comment: I agree with Mr. Dunn, adding and iif/switch to check every returned value will be troublesome to maintain and slow. I still think you should follow Dunn's comment or the first suggestion in my answer.